# Typescript isolatedModules `export type { T } from './file'` vs `export { type T } from './file'` syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app

When I copied some code from one of my create-react-app projects to another. I've got these kind of errors:

```
SyntaxError: .../index.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (3:47)

> 3 | export { default, type TimeInputProps } from "./TimeInput";
    |                        ^
```

The error is gone after changing the line to:

```
export { default } from "./TimeInput";
export type { TimeInputProps } from "./TimeInput";
```

One project works with both syntaxes but the other one only accepts the second syntax. Typescript version is 4.7.4 in both. What is the reason for it? Is there any difference? Couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Are there any differences in your `tsconfig.json` files?

Comment: There are, but I've tried completely copying one to another to make them equal - it had no effect on the described issue. I think it is related not with typescript but maybe with some webpack loader/babel plugin/eslint versions difference